# Commerce 2.x multicurrency / multiprice setting

Tags: 8, commerce

Is it possible to set two prices each with its currency for the same product so that it appears in two stores with correct price? For example, I have set up two stores one for Czech Republic with CZK as a currency and second one for Germany with EUR as a currency. Now I want to create a product (for example t-shirt) that should appear in both stores but with price for each store different. I haven't found a way to do that, could somebody please shed some light on this problem, or at least point me in the right direction, I am kind of lost here.

Thanks.

[edit]
Still not found the correct way of resolving this problem. I have created a search index and view based on the documentation, the view has two pages each for one store. If I create a product with just one variation, price and currency, then publish it in one of the stores it all works as it is supposed to, but if I create product with two variations and two prices with two currencies, publish it in both stores then it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_currency_resolver module will help you do this.

Comment: Thanks so much, in the end we did not go through with this particular project, so i just forgot about it, but this seems to be the correct solution.